# how to get cell value by index in pyspark?

Tags: mysql, sql, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I want to get cell value to pass to a where condition in SQL query. below one is my dataframe ab. data frame has only distinct values

```
+----------+--------+
|Months    |    YEAR|
+----------+--------+
|         3|    2018|
|         2|    2014|
+----------+--------+
```

based on these I need to pass value to SQL query

```
for i in range(0,ab.count()):
      query = "select * from customer where YEAR= "+ab['YEAR'][i]+" and Months="+ab['Months'][i]
      df = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ohcdemo",driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",query=query,user="root",password="root").load()
```

and it should append to data frame by writing SQL query not able to get value into SQL query

Answer (score 0):

Spark dataframes do not have ordering, so it is meaningless to specify a index. Also you are overwriting the dataframe in each iteration of the for loop.

To do what you want, I'd suggest doing a `join`. Note that I changed the `query` parameter in the JDBC reader.

```
df = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(
    url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ohcdemo",
    driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
    query="select * from customer",
    user="root",
    password="root"
).load()

joined_df = ab.join(df, ['Months', 'YEAR'])
```

Comment: is there any alternative for this  join will not work as expected

Comment: @SS what do mean by `not work as expected`? what error did you encounter?